# function Template with explicit type names

Tags: c++, function, templates

I've been reading some pages about `template`s.

I see that, `template`s are used like this:

```
template <typename T>
T func(T a) {...}
```

So it's for providing flexibility to use the same code for different type of variables.
And also, we can use specialization which seems only applies to class, it's like:

```
template <> class A<int> {....}
```

But I didn't find the kind of use like this:

```
template<int N, bool isVertical, bool isFirst, bool isLast>
static void filter(int bitDepth, Pel const *src, int srcStride, 
                   short *dst, int dstStride, int width, 
                   int height, short const *coeff);
```

It's called like this:

```
filter<N, false, true, true>(bitDepth, src, srcStride, dst, dstStride, width, height, coeff);
```

In this code, template is given real and absolute types, IMHO, we can just add another four parameters into filter's parameter list instead of using template.

So, why template are used like this?

Comment: I believe it's to ensure they are compile-time values (i.e constant expressions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`template`s are not functions.  `template`s are factories of functions, where the arguments determine which function is produced.

(`template` functions also have type deduction based off of arguments, but that just determines which function is produced by the `template` function factory).

So this:

```
template<int N, bool isVertical, bool isFirst, bool isLast>
static void filter(int bitDepth, Pel const *src, int srcStride, 
               short *dst, int dstStride, int width, 
               int height, short const *coeff);
```

doesn't define one `filter` function, but an entire family of such functions.

The arguments within the `<>` after `filter` are the arguments passed to the `template` function factory to determine which function is actually produced.

When these functions are produced by the factory (at compile time), the values passed into the `template` function factory are known.  So optimizing around these constants is really easy.

It is true that inlining and the as-if rule can allow compilers to take literal arguments, deduce that a given argument is a compile time constant, and compile a function with that constant included -- but this technique is both fragile and limited.

With a `template` factory produced function, it is an actual function.  So you can store a pointer to it and pass it around as a stateless function.

For a concrete example, suppose you want to process an image.  Now the practical way to process an image is to set up a scanline based function with some data, then iterate over the scanlines of the image, passing each one to the scanline based function.

On the other hand, many image transformations are per-pixel transformations.  Writing all of the optimized looping over those pixels in each image transformation function results in lots of copy-paste code.  But you cannot afford to pass in a pointer to a pixel based operation to a scanline processing function -- the overhead to dereference a pointer is more than a bit high when compared to typical per-pixel operations.

So instead you create a `template` function factory that takes a per-pixel function at compile time, and wraps it up in the iteration over pixels code.  The overhead just goes away.

What more, instead of a pixel operation you might pass in another `template` function factory (via a `template class`), so you can do things like set if you are doing `SSE` type assembly, how many pixels the per-pixel operation should process at a time, etc.

The result can be a bunch of code that is written with `if`s, seemingly full of branches and conditionals, but actually compiles down to a nearly completely flat and branchless scanline operation when you pass in all of the parameters as template arguments.

In short, `template`s help solve problems that traditionally where solved via code generation -- be it macros or 3rd party tools.  They are sufficiently powerful and convenient that people are using them for code generation in cases where you would never have bothered before, like generating custom containers for each user type, custom search algorithms, hashing algorithms, iteration, for loops, and a myriad of other tomfoolery.

Everything that `template`s can do can be done without them, but that is not surprising: beware the Turing tar pit, where everything is equivalent, but nothing of import is easy.  `template`s make a certain kind of code generation *easy*.

Comment: A quite comprehensive answer!  I'd go even further than "templates help solve problems that traditionally where solved via code generation" and say "templates are code generation, built into the language."  Hence "template meta-programming."  +1.

Comment: @JohnZwinck traditional code generation actually generates text which is then compiled as if you typed it in: `template`s don't do that (and many misunderstandings result if you think they do), so I wanted to distinguish between `template` type and function factories and traditional "code generation".

Comment: Fair enough.  Ironically some external code generators produce better diagnostics than C++ templates--even when the diagnostics are being emitted by a compiler which has no awareness of the code generation step per se!  Of course things have gotten a bit better recently for people using extremely recent compilers, but still.